# How would you add capabilities to Erlang without making a new language?

Tags: security, erlang, capability, parse-transform

I was wondering how someone would go about adding [Capability-based security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security) to Erlang without making it into a new language and preserving maximum backwards compatibility on the application side?

Comment: I was thinking parse transforms could be used to remove access to things like `erlang:processes()` as to not compromise the system without breaking system libraries. I was also thinking to make Pids unguessable for example something like `<0.48.202270464972395333011708598926446773344>` instead of `<0.48.0>` where `202270464972395333011708598926446773344` is a large random number. I have no idea if this makes sense to or not from a beam vm internals point of view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really are interested in this you should read the Master's thesis by Gustaf Naeser on [Safe Erlang](http://www.erlang.se/publications/xjobb/0109-naeser.pdf)

Comment: Interesting +1 for that!

Comment: Okay I guess this really answers my question.